# R igraph with multiple edges

Tags: r, vector, igraph

I have a dataset like below

```
Employee    address    Designation
E1          A1         D1
E2          A2         D2
E3          A1         D3
E4          A1         D1
E5          A3         D1
```

I need to create relation between employees which reside on same address and have same designation so I can create a graph edge (igraph)

I have used following code to draw the relationship between employee and address but how to add designation as well.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(tcrossprod(table(data)) - diag(nrow(data)), mode = "undirected")
plot(g)
```

For example, E1, E4 and related by address but they are related by Designation as well. So 2 lines will connect both. One would be red (for address) and another blue (for designation)

Comment: I though of creating two graphs and assigning `E(g1)$color <- "red"` to one and similarly to the other, and then to merge them. One problem is that then attributes disappears, while the other one is plotting multiple undirected edges.

Comment: I tried 

r1 <- data %>% select(Employee, address)
r2 <- data %>% select(Employee, Designation)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(tcrossprod(table(r1)) - diag(nrow(r1)), mode = "undirected") + graph_from_adjacency_matrix(tcrossprod(table(r2)) - diag(nrow(r2)), mode = "undirected")

Checking if this is giving correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you could do this more elegantly, but one option might be to reshape your data so that you have two edgelists and then combine them.

```
library(igraph)

data<-data.frame(Employee=paste0("E", c(1:5)),
                 Address=paste0("A", c(1:3,1,3)), 
                 Designation=paste0("D", c(1:3,2,3)))

g1<-graph.adjacency(tcrossprod(table(data[,c(1,2)])), diag=FALSE, mode="undirected")

el<-get.data.frame(g1)
el$e_type<-"Address"

g2<-graph.adjacency(tcrossprod(table(data[,c(1,3)])), diag=FALSE, mode="undirected")

el2<-get.data.frame(g2)
el2$e_type<-"Designation"

el_all<-rbind(el, el2)

final_g<-graph.edgelist(as.matrix(el_all[,1:2]))
E(final_g)$type<-el_all[,3]

E(final_g)$color<-ifelse(E(final_g)$type=="Address", "red", "blue")

plot(final_g)
```

[image]